# Emeril 360 Oven. How do i disable timer when baking?

Tags: baking, equipment

With the Emeril 360 oven, is it possible to use with out timer running? Can you turm off timer when baking?

Comment: Did you look in the manual before asking?

Comment: Sometimes on fiddly, supposedly clever products the best thing to do is to set an arbitrarily long time and cancel the program.  On my combi microwave, I set an hour for things that will take 20-30 minutes and need checking at the end